# Linq to Entity use relation of tables fill gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework

I have 3 Tables Customer,CustomerTicket,Ticket

```
Customer-->ID primary key
CustomerTicket-->ID,TicketNo where ID,TicketNo are foreign-key
Ticket-->TicketNo,Subject where TicketNo primary key
```

I am using linq to entity and want to show columns like this,

```
ID TicketNo Subject
1  12        Car
1  18       Home
2  23       Plane
```

Every unique ID can have Many TicketNo and every TicketNo has one unique Subject

```
Gridview.DataSource=from customer in entity.Customer 
join custicket in entity.CustomerTicket on customer.ID equals custicket.ID .....
```

I tried code like the above but in the end couldn't understand how to make the table as I want.How will code continue or is there any better way? Also note that entity framework took my CustomerTicket table and add it as navigation property ...

Answer (score 0):

Do the joins,  create an anonymous collection with select, create a binding datasource with the collection and set the datasource

```
var cusList=from customer in entity.Customer 
join custicket in entity.CustomerTicket on customer.ID equals custicket.ID  
select new  
{
  custicket.ID, 
  custicket.ticketno, 
  ticket.subject
};

var bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource=cusList;

Gridview.DataSource=bs;
```